# Best way to overlay an ESRI shapefile on google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis, kml, shapefile

What is the best way to overlay a shapefile in Google Maps?

After some reading suggests that, converting shapefile into KML and overlaying KML in Google map is an option. If that is the case, how do I convert a shapefile into KMLs?

I believe there would be a few open source tools available for this conversion. Can anyone point to a tool to covert a shapefile to KML without any loss of data?

Comment: gis.stackexchange may also be able to help, e.g. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68027/how-to-read-coordinates-from-shapefiles-and-overlay-on-google-maps

Answer (score 47):

I like using (open source and gui friendly) [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/) to convert the shapefile to kml.

Google Maps API supports only a [subset of the KML standard](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/mapsSupport.html).  One limitation is file size.

To reduce your file size, you can [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/)'s "simplify geometries" function. This "smooths" polygons.

Then you can select your layer and do a "save as kml" on it.

If you need to process a bunch of files, the process can be batched with Quantum GIS's ogr2ogr command from osgeo4w shell.

Finally, I recommend zipping your kml (with your favorite compression program) for reduced file size and saving it as kmz.

Comment: 1. ctrl-shift-v to load a shape file: http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/supported_data.html; 2. Save as KML per: http://www.townshipgis.com/resources/problems-and-workarounds/convert-shapefiles-to-kml

Answer (score 17):

*as of 12.03.2019 FusionTables is no more...*

Import the Shapefile into Google FusionTables ( http://www.google.com/fusiontables ) using http://www.shpescape.com/ and from there you can use the data in a number of ways, eg. display it using GoogleMaps.

Comment: The procedure itself worked well. In my case, however, a few shapes were not converted (e.g., coordinates were not converted).

Comment: this works. after the procedure, need to mark the fusion chart public access and add api key to the google maps

Comment: As many other experimental google products, also Google Fusion Tables will be killed soon https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/9185417

Answer (score 16):

I would not use KML. Instead, use [GeoJSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON) which you can natively consume in Google Maps API now. It is a newer feature that didn't exist from the original responses.

In any case, simply open the SHP file in [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/), and then you can output it in any format you like (KML, GeoJSON).

If you are using Google Maps for Work, I found a premium extension that handles loading shapefiles directly where you can just connect direct to the shapefile that you generate from ESRI. I did a search on the CMaps site and found this snippet which loaded US by state shapefile: https://gmapsplugin.net/cmapsanalytics/assets/shapes/usstates.shp

```
var cMap = new centigon.locationIntelligence.MapView();
    cMap.key([your_api_key]);


    cMap.layerNames(["Basic Shapes"]);
    cMap.dbfKeys([['Alabama','Alaska','Arizona','Arkansas','California','Colorado','Connecticut','Delaware','District of Columbia','Florida','Georgia','Hawaii','Idaho','Illinois','Indiana','Iowa','Kansas','Kentucky','Louisiana','Maine','Maryland','Massachusetts','Michigan','Minnesota','Mississippi','Missouri','Montana','Nebraska','Nevada','New Hampshire','New Jersey','New Mexico','New York','North Carolina','North Dakota','Ohio','Oklahoma','Oregon','Pennsylvania','Rhode Island','South Carolina','South Dakota','Tennessee','Texas','Utah','Vermont','Virginia','Washington','West Virginia','Wisconsin','Wyoming']]);
    cMap.userShapeKeys([['Massachusetts','Minnesota','Montana','North Dakota','Hawaii','Idaho','Washington','Arizona','California','Colorado','Nevada','New Mexico','Oregon','Utah','Wyoming','Arkansas','Iowa','Kansas','Missouri','Nebraska','Oklahoma','South Dakota','Louisiana','Texas','Connecticut','New Hampshire','Rhode Island','Vermont','Alabama','Florida','Georgia','Mississippi','South Carolina','Illinois','Indiana','Kentucky','North Carolina','Ohio','Tennessee','Virginia','Wisconsin','West Virginia','Delaware','District of Columbia','Maryland','New Jersey','New York','Pennsylvania','Maine','Michigan','Alaska']]); 
    cMap.labels([['Massachusetts','Minnesota','Montana','North Dakota','Hawaii','Idaho','Washington','Arizona','California','Colorado','Nevada','New Mexico','Oregon','Utah','Wyoming','Arkansas','Iowa','Kansas','Missouri','Nebraska','Oklahoma','South Dakota','Louisiana','Texas','Connecticut','New Hampshire','Rhode Island','Vermont','Alabama','Florida','Georgia','Mississippi','South Carolina','Illinois','Indiana','Kentucky','North Carolina','Ohio','Tennessee','Virginia','Wisconsin','West Virginia','Delaware','District of Columbia','Maryland','New Jersey','New York','Pennsylvania','Maine','Michigan','Alaska']]); 

    cMap.polyDataSources([centigon.locationIntelligence.CMapAnalytics.DATA_PROVIDERS.SHAPE_DATAPROVIDER]);
    cMap.layerTypes([centigon.mapping.Layer.TYPE.POLY]);
    cMap.locations([["https://gmapsplugin.net/cmapsanalytics/assets/shapes/usstates.shp"]]);

    cMap.panTo("USA");
    cMap.zoomLevel(3);
```

Answer (score 14):

Do you mean shapefile as in an [Esri shapefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile)? Either way, you should be able to perform the conversion using [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html), which is available in the [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) packages. You need the `.shp` file and ideally the corresponding `.dbf` file (which will provide contextual information).

Also, consider using a tool like [MapShaper](http://www.mapshaper.org/) to reduce the complexity of your shapefiles before transforming them into KML; you'll reduce filesize substantially depending on how much detail you need.

Answer (score 2):

[Free "Export to KML" script for ArcGIS 9](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14273)

[Here is a list](http://spatialnews.geocomm.com/articles/overviewofkmlconversionprograms/) of available methods that someone found.

Also, it seems to me that the most efficient representation of a polygon layer is by using Google Maps API's polyline encoding, which significantly compresses lat-lng data. But getting into that format takes work: use ArcMap to export Shape as lat/lng coordinates, then convert into polylines using Google Maps API.

Comment: Links are Broken!

Answer (score 2):

Just to update these answers, ESRI has included this tool, known as [Layer to KML](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000004n000000) in ArcMap 10.X.  Also, a [Map to KML](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000004p000000) tool exists.

Simply import the desired layer (vector or raster) and choose the output location, resolution, etc. Very simple tool.

Answer (score 1):

2018 already... I've found this fantastic online tool http://mapshaper.org/ to convert from ESRI shapefiles to SVG, TopoJSON, GeoJSON.

Here is the explanation of how to use it https://www.statsilk.com/maps/convert-esri-shapefile-map-geojson-format

Fast and straightforward! :)

Comment: but `mapshaper` doesn't have google map layers for which question was asked