# Overlaying shapefiles or raster over interactive maps

Tags: r, google-maps, openstreetmap, shapefile, googlevis

I'm using R, and I want to overlay some raster data (e.g. a temperature map from a model) over an interactive map which allows panning and zooming. Ideally, I'd like to overlay over Google Maps or OpenStreetMaps. The input data can be in shapefiles, KML, `raster` data or whatever comes in handy.

- I know I can easily do this non-interactively using either `googleVis`, `ggmap` or `RgoogleMaps`. But I do not want to use tiles, I want **interaction**! Zooming, panning etc., directly from the browser.
- `googleVis`, as far as I know, unfortunately only allows to show interactively points or addresses, not areas.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387042/best-way-to-overlay-an-esri-shapefile-on-google-maps) is very similar but I definitely want to try to do this using R. I can create the KML or geoJSON from R, but how do I overlay it from R directly?
- OpenStreetMaps is also fine, however I've not found any reference on how to overlay data over it from R, despite the fact that OSM seems to have [a pretty straightforward API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overlay_API).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `leaflet` package may be of interest for you. You can easily add a `raster` object. From the [documentation](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/raster.html)

> Two-dimensional RasterLayer objects (from the raster package) can be
>   turned into images and added to Leaflet maps using the addRasterImage
>   function.

And here is an example also from the [documentation](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/raster.html):

```
library(leaflet)
library(raster)

r <- raster("nc/oisst-sst.nc")
pal <- colorNumeric(c("#0C2C84", "#41B6C4", "#FFFFCC"), values(r),
  na.color = "transparent")

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addRasterImage(r, colors = pal, opacity = 0.8) %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal, values = values(r),
    title = "Surface temp")
```

Comment: That is absolutely excellent! Thanks. I really have no idea how I managed to miss this wonderful package.

Answer (score 6):

The **mapview** package has been developed for this particular purpose. It also comes with a variety of background map layers. For a short introduction to what **mapview** is capable of, feel free to browse the [package vignette](http://environmentalinformatics-marburg.github.io/web-presentations/20150723_mapView.html). Here, for example, is some code that displays locations of selected breweries in Franconian Switzerland overlaid by a sample Landsat 8 scene (band 10). Check out `?breweries91` and `?poppendorf` to retrieve information about the data used below and `?mapview` to grow familiar with the numerous costumization options.

```
## require package
# install.packages("mapview")
library(mapview)

## visualize breweries and add landsat 8 band 10
mapview(breweries91) + 
  poppendorf[[10]]
```

[image: mapview_viewer]

Comment: This is brilliant! Unfortunately I already implemented this using `leaflet`, but I really like this package. The quality, quantity and availability of R packages will never cease to impress me. Well done with the package!